# New to Javascript - For Loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Javascript and I'm looking at the for loop.

I'm trying to loop through 4 numbers which I've done successfully.

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    console.log(i + " and " + (i+1));
}
```

However I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
0 1 

0 2

0 3

0 4

1 2

1 3

...etc
```

Is that possible with a for loop?

Thanks

Terry

Comment: Yeah, just nest 2 loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think the question is ask for just one for loop.**

here is the correct answer you want to want:

```
for (i=0,j=0;i<5;i++) {
    console.log(j + " and " + (i+1));
    if(j<5&&i==4){
    j++;i=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your loop will be iterating through 5 numbers. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (count them)

You can achieve this by using two nested for loops

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(var j = i+1; j < 5; j++){
        console.log(i + " " + j);
    }
}
```

this will give you:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 2
...
3 4
```

NOTE: that this seems to match you pattern of not including "1 1" for example

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    for (j=i+1;j<5;j++) {
        console.log(i + " and " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops will do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
    console.log(i + ' and ' + j);
  }
}
```